# Plural of "dibamus"

Tags: species-identification, nomenclature, species, reptile, etymology

[*Migrated from English site.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222304/plural-of-dibamus#comment473277_222304)

---

[*Dibamus*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dibamus) is a genus of legless lizards in the family *Dibamidae*, of the infraorder *Dibamia*.

Genera are usually given in singular, so what is the correct plural of *Dibamus*?

Families and orders are usually given in plural, so what are the correct singulars of *Dibamidae* and *Dibamia*?

Bonus question: What is the etymology of the root *dibam-*?

Comment: There is no plural...Just call them _Dibamus_ species.

Comment: @Hav0k Not going to work. In reality, I want to know the plural of an item named Dibamus after the lizard. What are two of those called?

Comment: You could use the term "individual". 5 *dibamus* individuals.

Comment: If you try to use Dibami or Dibamuses etc. that will tamper the scientific name, which is an "identifier". i.e. it will indicate to a thing different from *Dibamus*.  Another fact, the name of a taxon (whatever its rank- species or genus or family etc) is the identifier for a "set", not individual. So the genus name *Dibamus* indicates a "set" or kind-of organism, and there could not be more-than-one *Dibamus* sets.

Comment: For a casual text (acceptable to public), you could try the term 5 *Dibamus* lizards; but from strict technical viewpoint, Lizard also indicate to a particular "set".

Comment: If you know a vernacular name (Is it Dibam lizard?), then you could use grammatical modifications of it, like 5 dibams or 5 dibam lizards. Since the vernacular-name is not the universal identifier, once in your text you have introduced the readers as your dibam lizards are *Dibamus* sp; then you can effortlessly continue with that vernacular name

Answer (score 2):

This is [advice from a website on plants](http://www.sarracenia.com/faq/faq5010.html), but its advice is equally valid for plants or animals.

> For example, if you wish to discuss several Pinguicula species, do you
> call them Pinguiculae or Pinguiculas? **The answer is that you can do
> neither!** Pinguicula is the name of the genus, a single group of plants
> which was very carefully named. If you make up a word like
> Pinguiculas, you are either implying that the genus has a letter "s"
> at the end (which it does not), or you are saying that there is more
> than one genus with the name Pinguicula---a logical absurdity.
>
> So it is just wrong
> to fabricate a plural form of a genus name. If you find yourself
> writing a sentence where you want to create a plural form of a genus
> (suppose you wanted to say, "I saw several Pinguiculas"), reconstruct
> the sentence slightly into something like "I saw many Pinguicula
> plants" or "I saw many Pinguicula species," whichever you meant. It is
> not only correct, but also much clearer.

There is a caveat to this, which is when the genus is borrowed into English as a loanword, for example, a plant of the genus *Delphinium* has the common English name "delphinium", or an ape of the genus *Gorilla* has the common English name "gorilla". In this case, the English word is pluralised into "delphiniums" and "gorillas". Note that it is still perfectly correct to say "I saw two apes belonging to the genus *Gorilla*", but it is just long-winded.

In your case, the lizard does not fall into this category, so you should word your phrase as "several *Dibamus* lizards" or a similar alternative phrasing.

Comment: Nice, but not going to work. My issue is a technical item that has been named Dibamus after the lizard. Now I don't know how to refer to several Dibam...

Comment: @NBZ That's a completely different question, but has the exact same answer. The plural of the technical term will differ based on the term itself. For example, the [Bittorrent client Azureus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vuze) is named after the frog *Dendrobates azureus*, and I would pluralise that as "I am running two Azureus bittorrent clients".

Comment: Fine, I guess it will be "Dibamus thruster blocks" or "Dibamus engines" then.

Comment: Yup, I would probably do the same in your shoes.